# I have a two form with a single submit button. Then how to i need to save the values of those form values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

form with the single submit. How to store that values in the data base

```
<%= form_for (@movie) do |f| %>
  //Movie
  <%= f.label :moviename,"Movie Name:"%>
  <%= f.text_field :moviename%>
  //Releases 
  <%= f.fields_for :release do |release_fields| %>
    <%= release_fields.label :theatre,"Theatre :"%>
    <%= release_fields.text_field:theatre%>
    <%= release_fields.label :city,"City :"%>
    <%= release_fields.text_field:city%>
    <%= release_fields.label :releasedate,"Release Date :"%>
    <%= release_fields.text_field:releasedate%>
    //Submit:
    <%= f.submit "Save The Movie"%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

this is the form with the single submit button.There an error it showing the unknown     attribute release can any on help with is issue Please

Comment: i suggest you format your question first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields_for` is expecting to access `@movie.release`, does that exist?